# Get more details about log messages

Tags: 7

I'm getting a lot of "Missing text format: 1." errors in my log. It seems to point to a bug where text formats used to get referenced by number in D6 (['format'] = '1') but now are referenced by a name in D7 (['format'] = 'plain_text').

How would I find where does bugs are?

Or a more general question: how can I get more details about error messages in the Drupal log?

Comment: Are you using the Workbench module?

Comment: no, but I saw that they have a similar issue in their issue queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess log means watchdog here. Generally, you only have what the developer passed to the watchdog.

You can try to parse the code for (a part) of the error message. There's a good chance that this points you to the code sending the watchdog, which in turn gives you more information about the problem.

Comment: I'm referring to "admin / reports / recent log messages". What code should I be parsing? The error shows on the user profile pages and I use a lot of blocks with views content.

Comment: Yes, that's the watchdog. - Well, just do a grep accros your drupal installation.

Comment: great idea! This will generate the error message: modules/filter/filter.module:725:    watchdog('filter', 'Missing text format: %format.', array('%format' => $format_id), WATCHDOG_ALERT);     How do I find out where it's called from?

Comment: First have look at the code right before the watchdog is called. What does it try to do, why is the watchdog triggered. If you need more information, install the devel module and add a ddebug_backtrace() statement right before the watchdog is called. Make sure you have the "access devel information" permission. It will give you a stack trace. Add dpm() lines for variables you want to have a look at. Or even more powerful: Take Eclipse and XDebug and add a break point at this line. But this could take some hours to set-up if you haven't already.